# Oddly wide spaces in subsection title

Tags: spacing, sectioning, horizontal-alignment, line-breaking

I have a problem, this is what it looks like:

[image]

And this is the code:

```
\subsection{Bakterienst\"amme und Anzuchtbedingungen}
```

Where does the huge whitespace come from?

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: well, in the code, there is only ONE whitespace and in the output, the spacing between the words is huuuuge.

Comment: But for others to find out why, you've got to post a compilable code example that shows the problem.

Comment: If this is a hyphenation issue, then there must be something "attached" to the end of "Anzuchtbedingungen" to make it want to (stretch out and) break at that point. What do you have immediately following the `\subsection{...}` definition?

Answer (score 4):

Obviously the whitespace comes from fully justifying. It can be fixed by switching to flush left aka ragged-right mode, at least for this heading, for example by

```
\subsection{\protect\raggedright Bakterienst\"amme und Anzuchtbedingungen}
```

I used `\protect` because the command is fragile and needs to be protected in a moving argument such as here. Note, you may decide to use the optional argument to get a different result for the table of contents and the page header, such as

```
\subsection[Bakterienst\"amme und Anzuchtbedingungen]{%
    \protect\raggedright Bakterienst\"amme und Anzuchtbedingungen}
```

The `ragged2e` package provides better commands which even allow hyphenation:

```
\subsection{\protect\RaggedRight Bakterienst\"amme und Anzuchtbedingungen}
```

Sadly, you did not provide an example. I simulate the effect of full justification and solution here, see how the small stretching is removed:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[textwidth=11.1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\begin{document}
\subsection{\protect\justifying Bakterienst\"amme und Anzuchtbedingungen}
\subsection{\protect\justifying\protect\RaggedRight Bakterienst\"amme
    und Anzuchtbedingungen}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Also consider to improve justification for example by

- loading the `microtype` package
- using `babel`
- using T1 font encoding

so making it possible to keep full justification with good results.

Comment: Just a small remark: `\protect` is not necessary in the mandatory argument if the optional one is used.