# Large spaces between words in subsection title

Tags: spacing, sectioning

I have a problem with the spacing in the header of a subsection. Only this particular heading has large spaces. It looks like this:

[image]

Here is MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twocolumn]{article}

\begin{document}

\section{Implementation}

\subsection{Reciprocal Velocity Obstacle (RVO)}


\end{document}
```

How do i fix this?

Comment: Possibly related: [Oddly wide spaces in subsection title](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23649/oddly-wide-spaces-in-subsection-title). Can you provide a MWE?

Comment: Most likely, the issue is that the sub-section header is being fully aligned.  As a one-time fix, you could include `\raggedright` in the title.  Ideally, you would like to make ragged the default condition for the presentation of subsection headers.

Comment: @Sam The example you linked worked. Thanks! I used the `\protect \raggedright` command.

Comment: For one time solution you can break line manually: `\subsection{Reciprocal Velocity Obstacle\\ (RVO)}`